# Osscilation of function on segment

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R},$ $M=\sup\limits_{[a,b]} f$ and $m=\inf\limits_{[a,b]} f$.

Also for any $x,t\in [a,b]$ we have $|f(x)-f(t)|<K$. Prove that $M-m\leqslant K$.

Proof: If for any $x,t\in [a,b]$ we have $|f(x)-f(t)|<K$ then $$-K\leqslant\sup\limits_{x,t\in [a,b]}(f(x)-f(t))\leqslant K.$$
But $$\sup\limits_{x,t\in [a,b]}(f(x)-f(t))=\sup\limits_{x\in [a,b]}f(x)+\sup\limits_{t\in [a,b]}(-f(t))=\sup\limits_{x\in [a,b]}f(x)-\inf\limits_{x\in [a,b]}f(x)=M-m$$ since $\sup(-A)=-\inf A$.
Hence $$-K\leqslant M-m\leqslant K.$$
Am I right? Can anyone check my proof please?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @mathematician, Also $M-m\geqslant 0$. Right? Hence $0\leqslant M-m\leqslant K$. Right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @mathematician, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Even if your proof seems correct, there are some elements which should be more justified. In particular the equality $$\sup\limits_{x,t\in [a,b]}(f(x)-f(t))=\sup\limits_{x\in [a,b]}f(x)+\sup\limits_{t\in [a,b]}(-f(t)).$$

On my side I would say.

For all $x,t \in [a,b]$ we have $$-K \le f(x)-f(t) \le K.$$ Hence

$$f(t)-K \le f(x) \le K +f(t)$$

Taking the $\sup$ on $x$ of the second inequality above, we get for all $t \in [a,b]$

$$M=\sup\limits_{x \in [a,b]} f(x)=K+f(t)$$ and then taking the $\inf$ on $t$

$$M \le K +\inf\limits_{t \in [a,b]} f(t) =K+m$$

Comment: because $\sup(A+B)=\sup A+\sup B$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes and also because you can delete the $\sup$ on a variable that is omited.

Comment: Good remark! How to understand strictly that $\sup \limits_{x,t\in [a,b]}f(x)=\sup \limits_{x\in [a,b]}f(x)$?

Comment: Because you have $\sup\limits_{x,t \in [a,b]} f(x) =\sup\limits_{t \in [a,b]}(\sup\limits_{x \in [a,b]} f(x))=\sup\limits_{x \in [a,b]} f(x)$ as the right hand side do not depends on $t$.